# How to make a jquery-ui widget draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need clear up some jquery-ui concepts and could use your help.

If I do the following:

```
$("<div></div>").draggable();
```

jquery-ui will create a draggable object that wraps the selected div. I have, however, created my own widget (using `$.widget("namespace.mywidget"`), so, my first question would be, what happens when invoking this?

```
$("<div></div>").draggable().mywidget();
```

I suppose a mess ensues. In any case, I would like to define properties for the drag method, so I'd like to put that inside my widget. The second question is therefore: how do I extend $.ui.draggable ? Do you have any good tutorial? Simply calling this does not seem to be enough:

```
$.widget( "namespace.mywidget", $.ui.draggable, {} );
```

Thanks a bunch for any insights!

Comment: what _does_ happen when you try to extend `$.ui.draggable` ?

Comment: @Alnitak nothing at all. I think I need to call the "superclass" constructor, but I don't know how to refer to it...

Answer (score 0):

Just include it inside of your plugin. Make sure you include jqueryUI before your plugin code.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myWidget = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).draggable();
        });

    };
})(jQuery)

$('<div></div>').myWidget();  // this should be draggable.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gJ3CN/2/

Comment: I don't believe that will work.  The effect is no different to doing `$('<div>').draggable()` outside of a plugin.

Comment: Thanks Julian, I'm not sure I follow you though. Perhaps you want to run this in the _create function?

Comment: It will do the same thing as calling it outside of the plugin. This is true. But I thought the purpose was to NOT have to call draggable outside of the plugin.
Also, the widget factory does the same thing as the clunky code above. It makes it more standard in terms of how your plugin is executed (which can be good, and bad).
I never really use widget(), but the _create function sounds like it would be the place to call your draggable.

Comment: @JulianRaya yes, I suppose if that's what's required then this may work.  Doing it in `_create` would be preferable, though.

Comment: @JulianRaya am I understanding you correctly that this is going to make every field in my widget "draggable"?. Wouldn't it be better to just call `this.element.draggable();` inside the constructor? In any case, my problem is that, if the element is draggable, when I catch it in a droppable, it contains the element itself (e.g. a div) but not the widget I'm working with

Comment: I just took a look at the widget docs and I believe you are correct. this.element.draggable() would be the same as my $(this).draggable();
It wont make every element in your plugin draggable, but each instance of the entire plugin will be draggable. so if you said $('#a, #b, #c).myWidget(); You would have a total of 3 draggable elements.

Answer (score 0):

Before using draggable, make sure the element is in the DOM:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo(document.body)
```

You can then chain together your widget and draggable:

```
   $('<div></div>').appendTo(document.body)
     .mywidget()
     .draggable();
```

You can set any parameters you'd like on each widget call.  I created an example at [jsfiddle.net/bseth99/LEY9A/](http://jsfiddle.net/bseth99/LEY9A/) that builds a simple custom UI widget as a reference and for demonstration purposes.